# JS/JQuery text to speech: How to chain audios?

Tags: javascript, jquery, audio, text-to-speech, promise

Given n different words:

```
var text = [ "bèijing Beijing Shanghai"]
var words= [ "bèijing", "Beijing", "Shanghai" ];
```

Given n different .ogg audio files with a known locations :

```
<!-- AUDIOS FILES -->
<audio id="id1" src="/audio/Zh-bèijing.ogg"></audio>
<audio id="id2" src="/audio/Zh-Beijing.ogg"></audio>
<audio id="id3" src="/audio/Zh-Shanghai.ogg"></audio>
```

I use JS `getElementById('...').play()`, which I run using an `onclick` event over an HTML element:

```
<!-- HTML -->
<div id="play" onClick="document.getElementById('id1').play();">
    <button>Play</button>
</div>
```

This allow me to play one audiofile.

Using one single onlick event, **how play the first audio, then when done chain to it the play of a second audio ?**

Starting fiddles with assets there : http://jsfiddle.net/J9wAB/

**Note:** I tried `document.getElementById('id1').play().done(document.getElementById('id2').play())`, but it plays both files simultaneously.

**EDIT:** I accepted one answer working on Firefox. Yet, this `addEventListener` based answer fails on on some browsers. An alternative promise base answer may be more successful.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/7198851/1974961

Comment: Does your `play()` method call really return a promise (that has a `.done()` method)?

Comment: Stack overflow needs to have newer answers to stuff like this. JavasScript up to ES6 2018 at least and this was asked and answered with ES5.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this :

```
$('#play').data('audio', $('audio:first')).on('click', function() {
    var self = this;
    $(this).data('audio').on('ended', function() {
        var n = $('audio').eq( $(self).data('audio').index('audio') + 1 );
        $(self).data('audio', n.length ? n : $('audio:first'));
    }).get(0).play();
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/J9wAB/4/)

It gets the first audio element in the document, and stores it in jQuery's data, and once it's played (the `onended` event) it get's the next audio element in the DOM and the next time the button is clicked, it playes that, and when there are no more audio elements, it starts from the beginning again.

If you really wan't to use the ID instead, it would be something like :

```
var audio = 1

$('#play').on('click', function() {
    $('#id' + audio).get(0).play();
    audio++;
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/J9wAB/7/)

To play all three on a single click, one after the other, you'd do

```
$('#play').on('click', function() {
    $('audio').on('ended', function() {
        $('audio').eq($(this).index('audio')+1).get(0).play();
    }).get(0).play();
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/J9wAB/14/)

Comment: thanks for this push. I'am however willing to "chain" these audios, which means I want that one single click read them 3 one after an other. (I admit it is not easy to explain). I +1ed you answer to thanks you already.

Comment: @Hugolpz - should be fairly easy, added to the answer !

Comment: Does the fiddle n⁰14 play the 3 sounds in your browser ? It just play the first on Chrome, but I am willing to valided your answer if it works on your browser.

Comment: I'm using chrome, and it plays all three sounds here ?

Comment: It just plays me the first sound-file, it should play me the 3 files, one after the other.

Comment: Works for me in OS X Firefox 25.0.1

Comment: Indeed, works on Firefox ! 1 click => 3 audios played as a sentence! Doesn't works on Chrome, but you answered the question and deserve a big validation.

Answer (score 2):

No jQuery needed, just listen for the *ended* event

The simple case is the following:

```
document.getElementById('id1').addEventListener('ended', function(){
    document.getElementById('id2').play();
});
```

Abstracted, it would look like  http://jsfiddle.net/J9wAB/13/

```
function chain(ids/* id, id, ... */) {
    function setHandler(first, next) {
      document.getElementById(first).addEventListener('ended', function(){
        document.getElementById(next).play();
      });   
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length - 1; i++) {
        setHandler(arguments[i], arguments[i+1]);
    }
}
chain('id1', 'id2', 'id3');
```

Comment: Works on Firefox ! 1 click => 3 audios played as a sentence! Chrome crash it. But thanks you :)

Comment: It didn't crash on my Chrome

Comment: Just upgraded to Chromium `Version 30.0.1599.114 Ubuntu 13.04 (30.0.1599.114-0ubuntu0.13.04.2)`, still failing.

Comment: Must be something with your ubuntu version of Chrome

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `onended="yourcallback()"` to start the next audio.

Look at this answer please: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7652194/2707424

Comment: could you be more precise for a newby like me.