# Playlist of audio files within HTML5 webapps?

Tags: javascript, mp3, web-audio-api, playlist, howler.js

Given an array of urls corresponding to as many audio files such :

```
     var playlistUrls = [
        "./audio/cmn-ni3.mp3",
        "./audio/cmn-hao3.mp3",
        "./audio/cmn-lao3.mp3",
        "./audio/cmn-mao3.mp3"
        ];
```

**How to play these files as a playlist [one at the end of an other] in the same order as the provided array of urls ?**

I have a preference to do that in the scope of howler.js, since [it provides various HTML5 fallbacks](http://howlerjs.com).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following does work, is scalable, and may be the a good start to achieve the upper cited function ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fzb4egwy/2/)):

```
var playlist = function(e) {
    // initialisation:
      pCount = 0;
      playlistUrls = [
        "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/8a/Zh-Beijing.ogg",
        "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/8a/Zh-Beijing.ogg",
        "./audio/a.mp3",
        "./audio/b.mp3",
        "./audio/c.mp3",
        "./audio/d.mp3"
        ], // audio list
      howlerBank = [],
      loop = true;

    // playing i+1 audio (= chaining audio files)
    var onEnd = function(e) {
      if (loop === true ) { pCount = (pCount + 1 !== howlerBank.length)? pCount + 1 : 0; }
      else { pCount = pCount + 1; }
      howlerBank[pCount].play();
    };

    // build up howlerBank:     
    playlistUrls.forEach(function(current, i) {   
      howlerBank.push(new Howl({ urls: [playlistUrls[i]], onend: onEnd, buffer: true }))
    });

    // initiate the whole :
        howlerBank[0].play();
}
```

Also, I made [a Github requested to add this feature into Howler.js](https://github.com/goldfire/howler.js/issues/191).

Please share back your variation on jsfiddle if you do one.

Comment: See also [JS/JQuery text to speech: How to chain audios?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20228004/) non-howlerJS answer and [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/J9wAB/14/)